# Mouse freezes briefly after being recognised

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, freeze

I am using an [ATEN US224 USB switch](http://www.aten.com/products/Mobility-&-USB/USB-Peripheral-Switches/2-Port-USB-Peripheral-Sharing-Device-~US224.html) to control my Windows and Linux PCs at work, in an attempt to reduce keyboard/mouse clutter on my desk. For security reasons the two PCs operate on separate networks so using `synergy` or similar is not an option.

Switching from the Windows to the Linux machine using the switch works seamlessly, and Ubuntu seems to pick up the mouse/keyboard in just over a second, which is more than tolerable even for frequent switching.

Switching to Windows however is a little irritating. Windows picks up the mouse very quickly (about 1 second), but then, after about another second, it freezes again briefly for a second or so before becoming responsive again.

You wouldn't notice this if you were just plugging your mouse in, but when you're switching between PCs all day it becomes noticeable and distracting, as you immediately start to use the mouse only for it to lock up again for a second. It would be easier if the mouse just wasn't responsive at all until it was fully responsive.

How can I figure out what Windows is doing that's causing it to hang just after I plug the device in? Or, can I do some tweaking to make windows pick up the mouse/keyboard more quickly and without interruption?

Answer (score 0):

I have your problem with another 'KVM' switch. I update the 'KVM' switch's driver and my issue is resolved.

Comment: Tom, thanks, that was a good idea. I tried looking for drivers but I wasn't able to find any (see http://www.aten.com/products/Mobility-&-USB/USB-Peripheral-Switches/2-Port-USB-Peripheral-Sharing-Device-~US224.html#.VxQLleJ95Ci)

Comment: Did you contact with company's support team?

Comment: No but that's a great idea. I'll post back with their response.